# Can the iOS device register the quantity of charge or electric field that is contacting the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any info about the voltage or electrical field being sensed by the Iphone's capacitive screen that can be used in a program?
Might this data be kept in a log or accessible via function calls?

Answer (score 1):

It's abstracted away - you can't get at it, or see it. I wouldn't be surprised if it was actually abstracted away in hardware, rather than software. As far as I know it's not logged anywhere either (that would be one huge log file if it did).

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is possible to see it from software (which is very unlikely), the only place where it would be accessible is from within the kernel. For apps, it is impossible to access raw touchscreen data.